# Iterating through integer by byte in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, iteration

I tried to iterate through an integer using a char pointer. My question is: Why is it stored in memory backwards? When I run the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int count, char** args)
{
    unsigned int number = 0xabcdef12;
    cout << "Number:\t\t" << hex << number << endl;
    cout << "Iterated:\t";

    unsigned char* pointer = (unsigned char*)&number;
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(number); i++)
        cout << hex << (unsigned int)pointer[i];

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Number:     abcdef12
Iterated:   12efcdab
```

I want to know if there is a way to force C++ to order the bytes, e.g.:

```
Number:     abcdef12
Iterated:   abcdef12
```

(Extra info: I want to do this because I want to iterate through a `struct` by byte and write the result to file.)

Comment: Lots of interesting info here:  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/95556/what-is-the-advantage-of-little-endian-format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you're on a "little-endian" system.  Some computers, including the x86 ones most of us use, are this way.  You can swap the byte order of an int with the standard function `htonl()`; the result will always be in "network byte order" which is the one you were expecting here.

Comment: "standard" - not the C++ standard!